# QTP: How to find the action name programatically?

Tags: qtp

There's Datatable.getsheet.getparameter ... etc and things for the data table. Is there something for actions?

I thought it would be something like Test.Actions("Name_of_action").name. It talks about this in the object model reference in the help... but I don't know the base class.

Also, where can I find a list of all the base classes? (by base class i mean things like the "Datatable" class)

edit: my last question is essentially asking if there's a MSDN for QTP classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions have a `Name` property accessible via automation.

```
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
MsgBox qtApp.Test.Actions(1).Name
```

It's all detailed in QTP's help under *HP QuickTest Professional Advanced References* => *HP QuickTest Professional Automation Object Model* (aka MSDN for QTP classes).

Answer (score 6):

```
curAction = Environment.Value("ActionName")
```

This will assign the current action name into a string variable.